# Amazon SQS ReceiveMessage receiving duplicates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

I have a simple Golang application which loops and receives messages from an SQS queue. If I send four messages to the queue and call `ReceiveMessage()` with `MaxNumberOfMessages` set to 1, the loop runs four times and receives the four messages.

For some reason, if I change `MaxNumberOfMessages` to 10, I receive 10 messages in every response (duplicates of the original 4 all mixed up), and the loop never stops. The API seems to send me the 4 messages forever. Even though I'm deleting them, but the ReceiptHandle is different for each instance.

Why is this happening?

```
// This loops seemingly forever and returns 10 messages (all duplicates) every time...
for {
  m, err := service.ReceiveMessage(&sqs.ReceiptMessageInput{
    MaxNumberOfMessages: aws.Int64(10),
    QueueUrl: &queueUrl,
    WaitTimeSeconds: aws.Int64(20),
  })

  for i := 0; i < len(m.Messages); i++ {
    service.DeleteMessage(&sqs.DeleteMessageInput{
      QueueUrl: &queueUrl,
      ReceiptHandle: m.Messages[i].ReceiptHandle,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the message visibility timeout set?

Comment: Hi Srikanth - 0 seconds.

Comment: Can you increase the visibility to 20secs and check?

Comment: Huh. Now behaving how I expect it to. Thanks!

Comment: When a message exceeds its _invisibility timeout_, it is assumed that the message processing failed. Therefore, the message is placed back on the queue so that it can be processed again. You were not providing enough time for the message to be processed. In general, the timeout should be set to 2-3 times the normal processing time so that it does not incorrectly trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the error for delete message? You shouldn't ignore errors.

```
 _, err := svc.DeleteMessage(&sqs.DeleteMessageInput{
    QueueUrl:      queueURL,
    ReceiptHandle: messageHandle,
})
// snippet-end:[sqs.go.delete_message.call]
if err != nil {
 fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Also refer the following documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/sqs-example-receive-message.html

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed checking for errors - none being returned.